# I have Created android app from angular 6 project using cordova, not able to call any api

Tags: java, android, cordova, angular6

I have created android apk from angular 6 project using cordova.
when I run this apk on virtual device or any mobile, its not able to connect to my backend server.

Do we need to any configuration changes or mention the backend server url ?

I referred this link for conversion: 
https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6

Already allowing all intent in config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
```

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: not any error i figured out, but its not able to connect with backend api.

Comment: did you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: @AkashChavda add  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in ApplicationManifest.xml file under application tag.